# Inorder traversal in a BST

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a balanced binary search tree of integers and I want to find the leftmost node which stores the integer greater or equal to a fixed number like `a` using a function like `ask(a)`.

for example suppose that I have added the following points in my tree, `8,10,3,6,1,4,7,14,13`

Then the tree would be like this:

[image]

now `ask(1)` should be `1`, `ask(3)` should be `3`, `ask(2)` should be `3` and so on.

I think that I can use Inorder traversal to write my `ask` function, But I don't know how.

Iv written this piece of code so far:

```
inorderFind(node->left, a);
if (node->key.getX() >= a)
    return node;
inorderFind(node->right, a);
```

The first argument is the current tree node and `a` is the `a` that is described above. I know that I can use a `bool` variable like `flag` and set it to `true` when the if condition holds, and then it would prevent from walking through other nodes of the tree and returning a false node. Is there anything else that I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Trees have the wonderful property of allowing queries through simple, recursive algorithms. So, let's try to find a recursive formulation of your query.

Say `LEFTMOST(u)` is a function which answers this question :

> Given the binary search subtree rooted at node `u`, with(possibly null) left and
>   right children `l` and `r`, respectively, what is the left-most node
>   with a value `>= a`?

The relation is quite simple:

```
LEFTMOST(u) = LEFTMOST(l) if it exists
              LEFTMOST(r) otherwise
```

That's it. How you translate this to your problem and how you handle concepts like "null" and "does not exist" is a function of your representation.